# AWS Lambdas with Docker images: do I have to create a different docker image per lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I have a big number of lambdas, all sharing the same libraries. Due to size constraints I can not package the libraries together with the lambda neither use the Lambda Layers, so I have created a Docker image (let's call it lambda_base:latest) with all the required libraries installed and deployed it in ECR.

Now, for every lambda, I have created a new Docker image based on lambda_base:latest where the only difference is that includes the lambda's code and it is working fine.

My question is, am I proceeding ok? I would expect to deploy the lambda a one and being able to chose as "runtime" lambda:latest instead whatever image that AWS uses to run the lambda but I don't find how to do that.

Maybe what I am doing is ok but I found weird to create a image for every single lambda.

Thanks a lot!!!

I have created

Answer (score 0):

First, your application Docker image would not be stored inside of the Lambda. The Docker image would be stored in AWS ECR, which is the Container Registry that AWS provides for its customers. You would build your image, tag your image and then publish your image to an ECR repository that you create. The image in this ECR repository can be utilized by any AWS Service that accepts a Docker image, whether it is Lambda, ECS, EKS, Batch, etc. It is not something specific to Lambda, in other words.

Second, I would create an ECR repo per application. I would not think of it as a 1:1 between lambda and ecr, but rather a 1:1 between application and ecr repo. Think of the ECR Repo as the container for a given application. So each repo would have a Dockerfile, which uses the From instruction as so:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 
COPY requirements.txt . 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}" 
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
```

So this app.py might be MyApp1. and it can be importing a bunch of other files that comprise of MyApp1. This corresponds to an ECR Repo you can call my-app-1. Then you will have a second application, where the app.py and imported files are vastly different and so you would have a second ecr repo to hold the layers of that application.

Then for your Lambda function parameters, you will specify the image uri, which refers to the ECR URI. You will specify your package type as "Image". Here is a rudimentary example in Terraform Infrastructure As Code to illustrate the point:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "function" {
  function_name     = "${var.name_prefix}-my-lambda${var.name_suffix}"
  description       = "My Lambda Function"
  image_uri         = var.image_uri
  package_type      = "Image"
  timeout           = var.timeout
  memory_size       = var.memory_size
  role              = var.role_arn
  tags              = var.tags
}
```

The image_uri variable would come from the ECR Repo that was created. So the variable would look something like this:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "repo" {
  name = "Your Repo Name"
}

resource "null_resource" "ecr_image" {
  triggers = {
    docker_file       = md5(file("${path.module}/../../Dockerfile"))
    app_file          = md5(file("${path.module}/../../app.py"))
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
      aws ecr get-login-password --region ${var.region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${local.account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.region}.amazonaws.com
      cd ${path.module}/../../
      docker build -f Dockerfile -t ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:${local.ecr_image_tag} .
      docker push ${aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}:${local.ecr_image_tag}
    EOF
  }
}

data "aws_ecr_image" "lambda_image" {
  depends_on = [
    "null_resource.ecr_image"
  ]

  repository_name = "Your Repo Name"
  image_tag       = local.ecr_image_tag
}


output "image_uri" {
  value = aws_ecr_repository.repo.repository_url}@${data.aws_ecr_image.lambda_image.id
}
```

In the above example, I am using Terraform, but you could just as easily reproduce the same scenario in CloudFormation or directly through the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Probably I didn't explain myself very well. What I am doing is what you describe: deploy the lamda indicating a docker image (deployed in ECR) containing all the code required (the specific for the lambda + libraries)
My question is: if I have 50 lambdas, do I have to repeat that process 50 times, creating 50 different docker images? My idea (probably not possible) was to deploy the lambda indicating the lambda code + a docker image "base" with all the libraries, so with that I would have only one docker image instead 50. 
Thanks!!

Comment: You do not need to create 50 different docker images. In the code example I gave above, I only create the Docker Image once. And then I can create 50 Lambdas and all can reference the same image in ECR via the image uri property. You can reference the "latest" tag in ECR in all of your lambdas. Or you can create a tag and have 10 of your lambdas reference one tag and another 20 reference another tag.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused :-( Every lambda has a different code so, where do you specify that code in your lambda?
When creating the lambda as you specify (with image_uri) that image must contain the "base code" + lambda code, so for another lambda the code is different (not the base code) and that means another image must be created.
My images look like:

FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
COPY requirements.txt  .
RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt --target "${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}"
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT} ====>app.py changes for ever lambda
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
Thanks!!!

Comment: In this case, I would use the "FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8" in a Dockerfile per application, then copy project specific code in the Dockerfile. So yes I would create an application specific ecr repo.

Comment: So really the way I would think about it is that there isn't a 1:1 between lambda and ecr repo. Rather, it is a 1:1 between application and ecr repo. So each application will be in its own ecr repo.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel, this is what I thought, but that means 1 image per lambda ... To avoid that, probably I will explore the EFS approach, where the libraries are in a EFS mounted in the lambdas and the lambda just containing its code. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use different images for every Lambda function. It is possible to override `command`, so you can have the same image for all functions and just override `command` to point to specific handler for each of the functions. Here are the docs for Serverless Framework where it is specified how you can override `command`: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#referencing-container-image-as-a-target

If you are not using Serverless Framework, you can override it in similar way in raw CloudFormation or manually via AWS UI.